# Integer partitions in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, maple

I'm porting a function that takes in an integer and spits out the integer partitions of that number, that is

```
(partitions 4)
```

should yield

```
((4) (3 1) (2 2) (2 1 1) (1 1 1 1))
```

that is, partition lists are lex-sorted first by largest part, then second-largest part, etc. And the sum is the integer we are partitioning.

In the maple package SF by John Stembridge this is produced by the following subroutine that produces the partitions with diagram within a box defined by `row` and `col` so that `SF/Par/sub(n,n,n)` is what I want:

```
`SF/Par/sub`:=proc(n,row,col) local i;
   if n=0 then [[]]
     elif col=0 then []
     else 
       [seq(op(map((x,y)->[y,op(x)],`SF/Par/sub`(n+i,-i,col-1),-i)),
         i=-min(row,n)..-iquo(n+col-1,col))]
  fi 
end:
```

where iquo is `(floor (/ x y))`

The question is how to get from

```
(2 (2 ()) (1 (1 ())))
```

the result

```
((2 2) (2 1 1))
```

?

**Edit**

The following is my attempt

```
(defun partitions (n row col)
  ""
  (block nil
    (if (= n 0) (return '(())))
    (if (= col 0) (return '()))
    (loop for i from (- (min row n)) to (floor (/ (- (+ n col) 1) col))
       collect (cons (- i) (partitions (+ n i) (- i) (- col 1))))))
```

It runs and terminates but that's all I can say for it.

`(partitions 3 3 3)` yields

```
((3 NIL) (2 (1 NIL) (0 (0) (-1)) (-1 (-1) (-2))) (1 (1 (1 NIL) (0) (-1)) (0 (0) (-1) (-2)) (-1 (-1) (-2) (-3))) (0 (0 (0) (-1) (-2) (-3)) (-1 (-1) (-2) (-3) (-4)) (-2 (-2) (-3) (-4) (-5))) (-1 (-1 (-1) (-2) (-3) (-4) (-5)) (-2 (-2) (-3) (-4) (-5) (-6))))
```

I want it to return `((3) (2 1) (1 1 1))`

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: @RainerJoswig See edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `COND` instead of `BLOCK`/`RETURN`

```
(defun partitions (n row col)
  (cond ((= n 0) ...)
        ((= col 0) ...)
        (t (loop ...))))
```

Then you could use `ZEROP` instead of `(= X 0)`, and `1-` instead of `(- X 1)`. I don't see any reason to make `I` negative either (you can use the loop keyword `DOWNTO` to count down). `FLOOR` takes a divisor as an optional argument, so you can write `(FLOOR X Y)` instead of `(FLOOR (/ X Y))`.

With these changes:

```
(defun partitions (n row col)
  ""
  (cond ((zerop n) '(()))
        ((zerop col) '())
        (t (loop for i from (min row n) downto (floor (1- (+ n col)) col)
                 collect (cons i (partitions (- n i) i (1- col)))))))

(partitions 3 3 3)
;=> ((3 NIL) (2 (1 NIL)) (1 (1 (1 NIL))))
```

Those `NIL`s are caused by the nested list in the first clause of the `COND`. Remember that an empty list is the same as `NIL`. If you change it to just `'()`, the result will be `((3) (2 (1)) (1 (1 (1))))`.

To get rid of those extra inner lists, you could use an inner function that builds the result and pushes it into a list when `N` is zero.

```
(defun partitions (n row col)
  ""
  (let ((result (list)))
    (labels ((%partitions (n row col acc)
               (cond ((zerop n) (push (reverse acc) result))
                     ((zerop col))
                     (t (loop for i from (min row n) downto (floor (1- (+ n col)) col)
                              do (%partitions (- n i) i (1- col) (cons i acc)))))))
      (%partitions n row col '())
      (nreverse result))))

(partitions 3 3 3)
;=> ((3) (2 1) (1 1 1))
(partitions 4 4 4)
;=> ((4) (3 1) (2 2) (2 1 1) (1 1 1 1))
```

A bit longer, but, at least IMO, simpler way to solve the problem:

```
(defun partitions (n)
  (let ((result (list)))
    (labels ((%partitions (n largest-number acc)
               (cond ((< n 1) (push (reverse acc) result))
                     (t (loop for l from largest-number downto 1
                              do (loop for i from (floor n l) downto 1
                                       do (%partitions
                                           (- n (* l i))
                                           (1- l)
                                           (append (make-list i :initial-element l)
                                                   acc))))))))
      (%partitions n n '())
      (nreverse result))))

(partitions 3)
;=> ((3) (2 1) (1 1 1))
(partitions 4)
;=> ((4) (3 1) (2 2) (2 1 1) (1 1 1 1))
(partitions 5)
;=> ((5) (4 1) (3 2) (3 1 1) (2 2 1) (2 1 1 1) (1 1 1 1 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you already got a working answer, here are some comments about your coding style:

```
(defun partitions (n row col)
  ""
  (block nil
    (if (= n 0) (return '(())))
    (if (= col 0) (return '()))
    (loop for i from (- (min row n)) to (floor (/ (- (+ n col) 1) col))
       collect (cons (- i) (partitions (+ n i) (- i) (- col 1))))))
```

`""` can be omitted, since it is useless and does not contain documentation.

`DEFUN` already sets up a block, but it is named `partitions`. So

```
(defun partitions (...)
   (block nil ... (return ...) ...)
```

would be

```
(defun partitions (...)
   ...
   (return-from partitions ...)
   ...)
```

`(if (foo) (bar))` is often written as `(when (foo) (bar))`.
Because `(if (foo) (progn (bar) (baz)))` is `(when (foo) (bar) (baz))`.

Using `(block ... (if ... (return ...)) (if ... (return...)...)` is unusual in Lisp. `IF` typically returns a value, so additional control flow using `RETURN` or `RETURN-FROM` is not necessary. Instead of

```
  (block nil
    (if (= n 0) (return '(())))
    (if (= col 0) (return '()))
    (loop for i from (- (min row n)) to (floor (/ (- (+ n col) 1) col))
       collect (cons (- i) (partitions (+ n i) (- i) (- col 1))))))
```

one would write:

```
(if (= n 0)
    '(())
  (if (= col 0)
      '()
    (loop for i from (- (min row n)) to (floor (/ (- (+ n col) 1) col))
          collect (cons (- i) (partitions (+ n i) (- i) (- col 1))))))
```

Since these nested `If`s are quite common in Lisp code, the `cond` construct makes it a bit easier to write. The code also won't be moving to the right with each clause:

```
(cond ((= n 0)
       '(()))
      ((= col 0)
       '())
      (t
       (loop for i from (- (min row n)) to (floor (/ (- (+ n col) 1) col))
             collect (cons (- i) (partitions (+ n i) (- i) (- col 1))))))
```